# search among rows of matrix and return values from column in R

Tags: r, apply

In R, I have a matrix `M` of the form

```
lower upper value 
0.1   0.2  1.2 
0.2   0.3  2.4
0.3   0.4 -0.3
```

And a vector `v` with values in (0,1). For each value in `v`, I want to find the corresponding row in `M` such that the value is between the 'lower' and 'upper' values in that row, and get the corresponding number from the `value` column. The output should be a vector `y` of the same length as `v` where each element of `y` is the relevant 'value' as described above. How should I do this? I know I need to use the `apply` function but can't think of the most efficient way.

For example: For the `M` above, suppose `v = c(0.12, 0.34)`. Then the expected output is `y = c(1.2, -0.3)`

Comment: Are they cutoffs always so that the `upper` is the next row's `lower`?

Comment: @thelatemail yes

Comment: could you give an example of v and the expected outcome

Comment: For the ```M``` above, suppose ```v = c(0.12, 0.34)```. Then the expected output is ```y = c(1.2, -0.3)```.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `sapply` to pull `value` that fits the condition from `v`.

```
sapply(v, \(x) M[x > M[, "lower"] & x < M[, "upper"],][["value"]])

#[1]  1.2 -0.3
```

**Data**

```
M <- structure(c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 1.2, 2.4, -0.3), .Dim = c(3L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("lower", "upper", "value")))

v = c(0.12, 0.34)
```

Comment: M is a matrix and not a data.frame

Comment: @KU99 easy to convert

Comment: @KU99 Updated to work on a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

```
M[findInterval(v, c(M[1,'lower'], M[,'upper'])), 'value']
[1]  1.2 -0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cut` with each of the `v` values to find which range it falls into:

```
# example data for `v`:
set.seed(1)
v <- round(runif(5, min=0.1, max=0.4),2)
#[1] 0.18 0.21 0.27 0.37 0.16

M[, "value"][cut(v, c(M[1, "lower"], M[, "upper"]))]
#[1]  1.2  2.4  2.4 -0.3  1.2
```

Where `M` was:

```
M <- as.matrix(read.table(text="lower upper value 
0.1   0.2  1.2 
0.2   0.3  2.4
0.3   0.4 -0.3",  header=TRUE))
```